# CustomVision.ai Object Detection vs Image Classification

Tags: classification, object-detection, microsoft-custom-vision

I want to use CustomVision.ai to detect pack of cigarettes within a shopping cart. I have tons of images of contents of shopping carts **without** cigarettes, and several images of the content **with** cigarettes. All images are taken from the same angle, like 1 meter above the cart.

So my question is, should I rather use CustomVision.ai with Object Tracking to define the area of the cigarettes or should I use a classifier to identify just all images with cigarettes, since I could also use tons of Negative examples here.
The resolution of these images is 640x480px.

Here is a sample image:
[image]

Comment: Does all the cigarettes packs have the same design?

Comment: From my experience with Custom Vision, I would use Object Detection. You will need a lot of samples with packs to get a correct precision and recall...

Comment: No, they look different. I'd say it is like 10-20 different packs.
But yeah, I am currently collecting images now with cigarettes and try out the Object Detection. Thanks

Comment: Have a good luck. In any case, if you start by object detection and want to test classification later, you can still use Custom Vision API to copy the images and transform the bounding boxes into image tags. I may create a github repo for that kind of process in the next few weeks (I already have it but needs to clean it to be released publicly)

Comment: That would be awesome. Would be cool if you could give me an update once you are ready. Cheers!